# Jquery update count on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have an HTML snippet as below

```
var useful, cool, funny;

'<ul data-component-bound="true" class="voteset'+data[i]['review_id']+'">'+
    '<li class="useful ufc-btn" id="1">'+
      '<a href=javascript:vote('+data[i]['review_id']+',"useful") rel="useful"><span>Useful</span></a>'+
        '<span>'+useful+'</span>'+
    '</li>'+
    '<li class="funny ufc-btn" id="2">'+
      '<a href=javascript:vote('+data[i]['review_id']+',"funny") rel="funny"><span>Funny</span></a>'+
        '<span>'+funny+'</span>'+
    '</li>'+
    '<li class="cool ufc-btn" id="3">'+
      '<a href=javascript:vote('+data[i]['review_id']+',"cool") rel="cool"><span>Cool</span></a>'+
        '<span>'+cool+'</span>'+
    '</li>'+
    '<span class="vote'+data[i]['review_id']+'"></span></ul>'+
'</div>';
```

Each review have 3 buttons useful, cool and funny. How can i increase `<span>` count inside each button when i perform click operation.Below is what i tried but doesn't work.Thanks

```
function vote(reviewId,status) {
    $('.vote'+reviewId).text('posting ...');
    $('.voteset'+reviewId).click(function(){
      var updatevote = $(this).find("li>span").text();
      updatevote = updatevote + 1;
      $(this).next('span').html(updatevote);
    });
}
```

Comment: if the markup is dynamically created, you might need `delegate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parseInt` will cause `NaN` issue if the string is empty `""`, instead try `Math.floor`

```
function vote(reviewId,status)
{

    $('.vote'+reviewId).text('posting ...');
    $('.vote'+reviewId).text('posting ...');
        var $span = $('.voteset' + reviewId + ' li.' + status + ' span:eq(1)');
        $vote = Math.floor($span.text()) + 1; 
        $span.html($vote);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `updatevote` is going to be interpreted as text, rather than a number. Try

```
var updatevote = parseInt($(this).find("li>span").text(), 10);
```

Comment: you should always use a base with parseInt: `parseInt($(this).find("li>span").text(), 10);`

Comment: Ack, thanks for pointing that out. It would have been an unpleasant suprise if the string accidentally started with a 0. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var updatevote = +$(this).find("li>span").text(); // Convert to number

updatevote++;
```

Also `$(this).find("li>span")`  will give you an object that contains all the spans inside li.. I see there are three of them inside 3 different li's

How are you handling that..

Answer (score 0):

there is a general problem here with your event binding

```
function vote(reviewId,status) {
    $('.vote'+reviewId).text('posting ...');
    $('.voteset'+reviewId).click(function(){ // <-don't need this since you call vote directly from a#href
      var updatevote = $(this).find("li>span").text();
      updatevote = updatevote + 1;
      $(this).next('span').html(updatevote);
    });
}
```

this should work:

```
function vote(reviewId,status) {
    $('.vote'+reviewId).text('posting ...');

    var $span = $('.voteset' + reviewId + ' li.' + status + ' span');
    var updatevote = parseInt($span.text(), 10);

    updatevote = updatevote + 1;
    $span.text(updatevote);

}
```